Sequence-series a double summation problem.
$$
\mbox{If}\quad
X =
\sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ 50}
ij\,\left(-1\right)^{i + j}
$$

Find $\operatorname{S}\left(X\right)$ where $\operatorname{S}\left(n\right)$ denotes the sum of digits of $\left\vert n\right\vert$.
I have tried to bring this into $2$ summations with limits $i = 1$ to $49$ and $j = 2$ to $50$ so basically,
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{49}\sum_{j = 2}^{50}ij\,\left(-1\right)^{i + j} =
\sum_{i = 1}^{49}i\,\left(-1\right)^{i}
\sum_{j = 1}^{50}j\,\left(-1\right)^{j}
$$

Now,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{49}i\left(-1\right)^{i} = & \
-1 + 2 - 3 + \cdots - 49 = 2 + 4 + \cdots +48
\\ &\ -\left(1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots 49\right)
\\[5mm] = & \ 2\left(1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots +24\right) -49^{2}
\\[3mm] = & \ 24 \times 25 - 24^{2} = {\large 24}
\end{align}
$2_{\rm nd}$ sum can be calculated similary, so I want to ask that

Is the double summation correct ( The limits to be precise ).
Is the simplification good enough ?.

Thank you !.

i) No, it isn't correct because, there, you're summing over the pairs $(i,j)$ such that $1\le i\le 49\land 2\le j\le 50$, whereas in the original question you had to sum over the ones such that $1\le i<j\le 50$.

How should I proceed then?

Hint: $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{50}k(-1)^k\right)^2=2X+\sum_{k=1}^{50}k^2$.

That helps! Thank you.
